# what is thread created myself and main thread running sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, program-entry-point

```
public class ThreadTest extends Thread {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ThreadTest().start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      System.out.format("%s %d\n", Thread.currentThread(), i);
    } 
  }
   public void run() {
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       System.out.format("%s %d\n", Thread.currentThread(), i);
     } 
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 0
Thread[main,5,main] 0
Thread[main,5,main] 1
Thread[main,5,main] 2
Thread[main,5,main] 3
Thread[main,5,main] 4
Thread[main,5,main] 5
Thread[main,5,main] 6
Thread[main,5,main] 7
Thread[main,5,main] 8
Thread[main,5,main] 9
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 1
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 2
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 3
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 4
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 5
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 6
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 7
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 8
Thread[Thread-0,5,main] 9
```

I am confused about the order that threads running on. When new ThreadTest.start, it will run run() method first. But why it output 0 and continued to run main thread, could you explain the output for me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: thread order decided by thread scheduler. not programmer.

Comment: both will run parallely try to add `Thread.sleep(1000);` in both loops and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println` is a synchronized method and when a thread grabs a lock it has preference in grabbing the lock again.  In this case, `main` manages to get the lock and keeps getting it until the main loop finishes.  If you run this again, you are likely to get the output in a different order.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thank you Peter